# C function isn't working

Tags: c

I am writing a function `Calculate_age_when_Trump_elected(int year_born)` to return a result and assign a value to `age_when_Trump_elected`.

The result should be the `YEAR_TRUMP_ELECTED` minus the year of Trump was born but currently it just shows the input that the user enters.

"terminal_user_input.c" is just a file for functions  `read_string` and `read_integer`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "terminal_user_input.c"

#define YEAR_TRUMP_ELECTED 2016


// A very basic  read boolean function

bool read_boolean(const char* prompt)
{
    my_string answer;
    bool result;

    answer = read_string(prompt);
    answer.str[0] = (char) tolower(answer.str[0]);

    switch (answer.str[0]) {
        case 'n':
            result = false;
            break;
        case 'x':
            result = false;
            break;
        default:
            result = true;
    }

    return result;
}

int Calculate_age_when_Trump_elected(int year_born)
{
    int result;
    result = YEAR_TRUMP_ELECTED - year_born;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    my_string name;
    int age_when_Trump_elected;
    int year_born;
    bool brexiter;

    name = read_string("What is your name? ");

    year_born = read_integer("When you were born? ");
    age_when_Trump_elected = Calculate_age_when_Trump_elected(year_born);
    printf("You were %d years old when Trump was elected\n",year_born);

    brexiter = read_boolean("Are u a Brexit support? ");

    if (brexiter == true)
    {
       printf("%s is a Brexit supporter\n",name.str);
    }
    else
    {
       printf("%s isn't a Brexit supporter\n",name.str);
    }

    read_string("Type 'exit' to continue ");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `int Calculate_age_when_Trump_elected(int year_born)` ends with `return 0;` instead of `return result;`.  Or better yet just turn the calculation into a C MACRO, e.g. `#define Calculate_age_when_Trump_elected(int year_born) (YEAR_TRUMP_ELECTED - year_born)` .

Comment: I've reformatted your code to fix the indentation. You'll get better responses on SO if your code is formatted nicely. It makes it easier to read, and sometimes bugs will become much more obvious when the code is easier to follow.

Comment: You need to print `age_when_Trump_elected` instead of `year_born`. Then following ergohack's comment, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `Calculate_age_when_Trump_elected`. It will always return `0`. You should return the `result` variable instead.